# How to Write bson Array to ResponseWriter

Tags: mongodb, go, deserialization, bson

I am writing code in GoLang. As part of it, I generated bson array by querying a collection in MongoDB using `github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo`, `github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson`. I need to write this response to http.ResponseWriter. When I attempt to do this using `json.Marshal(BsonArrayReceived)`, response that is written to ResponseWriter has different document structure than JSON document structure stored in MongoDB. So, wanted to know the right way to write query results to ResponseWriter.

Let's say there are two documents that meet my query criteria - cat, dog

```
cat := bson.D{{"Animal", "Cat"}}
dog := bson.D{{"Animal", "Dog"}}
```

So resultant bson Array I am creating would be something like below

```
response := bson.A
response = append(response, cat)
response = append(response, dog)
```

My current code that did not work is below

```
writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")    
json.err := json.Marshal(response)
writer.Write(json)
```

Expected output would be

```
[{"Animal":"Cat"},{"Animal":"Dog"}]
```

Actual output I receive is

```
[{{"Key":"Animal"},{"Value":"Cat"}},{{"Key":"Animal"},{"Value":"Dog"}}]
```

So my question is how do I write to ResponseWriter so I preserve the JSON document array structure. I prefer not to use custom Marshal/UnMarshal as that would mean solution is specific and need changes if I change JSON structure

Comment: Define a struct and put the appropriate `json` and `bson` tags on the fields.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like type jsonArrayResp struct {Type string `bson:"Animal"` `json:"Animal"`}. If so, when my new response is {"Non-Living": {"Stone":"Marble"}}, I would get issues. So is there any generic method to translate bson.A to []byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bons.M` instead.

```
cat := bson.M{"Animal": "Cat"}
dog := bson.M{"Animal": "Dog"}
response := bson.A{}
response = append(response, cat)
response = append(response, dog)
writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
json, _ := json.Marshal(response)
writer.Write(json)
```